# Blending two transitions simultaneously in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have started learning **D3** and was playing around a bit with it. 
I have created an small *animation*. However it is not playing out exactly how I wanted.

Here's the *animation*.   ---> [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/DAEvQ/)

Now if you see in the **JS**, there is a small bit of code where the transition of the circles takes place. Below is the code.

**Transitions**

```
 C.transition()
            .attr("cy", 150)
            .duration(2000)
            .each("end", function () {
            d3.select(this).transition()
            .attr("cx", 150)
            .duration(2000);
```

What I want is that both the vertical and horizontal transactions to happen simultaneously.
I know that **D3** is not a widely used library but I'm pretty sure I will get help from the SO community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put both attributes together in one animation (updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DAEvQ/1/)

```
   C.transition()
        .attr("cy", 150)
        .attr("cx", 150)
        .duration(2000)
```

Comment: @AnaMaria Well you should've really figured that out on your own if you was able to come up with chained animations in the fiddle. =)

Comment: I did. Actually now i think my question was something else. I have touched this bit after a long time. I think i asked the wrong question